# Re assign foreign ID without conflict

Tags: php, mysql

I have a `main` table with a primary key (`ÍD`) and a `linked` one.

**Existing Data**

Main

```
ID | name
=========
1  | foo
2  | bar
3  | loo
4  | zoo
```

Linked

```
main_id
=======
     1
     1
     2
     2
```

There are connections to the first entries of `main` (1,2) in the `linked` table.

Now new data gets imported from the same structure:

**Import Data**

```
ID | name
=========
1  | new_foo
2  | new_bar
3  | new_loo
4  | new_zoo
```

and

```
main_id
=======
     3
     4
     3
     1
```

During the import process the `ID`s of the `main` table will get new ids (done by a script)

```
ID | name
=========
1  | foo
2  | bar
3  | loo
4  | zoo
5  | new_foo
6  | new_bar
7  | new_loo
8  | new_zoo
```

but the `main_id` will still have the ids from the imported data:

```
main_id
=======
     1 
     1 
     2 
     2 
     3  => should be 7
     4  => should be 8
     3  => should be 7
     1  => should be 5  => * comment below
```

*I cannot simple update `linked` like:

```
UPDATE linked SET main_id = 5 WHERE main_id = 1
```

as it would update the first two rows as well.

**So how can I map these field with the new primary ID of `main`?**

- I could add a high number to the `main_id` before import like

  `UPDATE linked SET main_id = main_id + 10000000`
- do the import
- apply the real ID

  `UPDATE linked SET main_id = %realID WHERE main_id = %importedID`
- return my temporary ID back to the original.

  `UPDATE linked SET main_id = main_id - 10000000 WHERE main_id > 10000000`

The problem is pretty obvious: This doesn't work well (or at all) if the IDs are higher than 10.000.000 or the temporary id is higher than BIGINT (9223372036854775807).

It could work with a clone of the table but this may cause a problem in memory consumption as the `linked` table can get pretty big.

I'm sure there's a "best practice" way of doing this.

Comment: This problem appears to be essentially insoluble. You have no PRIMARY KEY

Comment: your sample is not clear  ..  try explain better  ..  (you have the same id with two different values... )

Comment: "Now new data gets imported from the same structure" - as far as I understand, new_foo != foo, but have the same id. And when you imported the data, old new_foo id is ignored and a new id is generated?

Comment: And what is '%'?

Comment: "but the main_id will still have the ids from the imported data" - why? Can't you use the newly generated id that is inserted into the main table?

Comment: Can you explain, how you do the import? Where the imported data is stored? Better show the code.

Comment: Why can't the script that changes the `id` values in the imported data for the `main` table simultaneously change the `main_id` values in the other set of imported data?

Comment: Theres one primary key in the `main` table. "new_foo" is from the import table and share the same foreign ID as "foo" from the existing data. The new primary id for "new_foo" gets applied automatically but I need to update the `linked` table with that ID (which is known as `%realID`)

Comment: @Nick because it may convert old IDs to new one. `UPDATE linked SET main_id = %realID WHERE main_id = %importedID` : `%importedID` could be a `%realID` already so I make sure it's not by adding 10mio.

Comment: @Xaver ""new_foo" is from the import table and share the same foreign ID as "foo" from the existing data." - so, there are 3 tables: main, import and linked. Are they in the same database or import is being loaded from a file?

Comment: there are 4: main, linked, main_import, linked_import, The structure is the same but the database is not. If you know the WordPress import its basically that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The steps are:

1. Pick last ID in `Main` table: `select @lastId := max(ID) from Main;`
2. Just shift all IDs, that are to be written in `Linked` table, by `@lastId`.
   Something like this: `insert into Linked select ID + @lastId from Imported_linked_data`

No extra steps needed.

Answer (score 0):

You can add the new entries in the `Main` table and let the AUTO_INCREMENT column generate the Id of the new row (as it should). For each row you cache the generated Id in an associative array, which maps the old Id to the new generated Id.

After that you insert the entries for the `linked` table. Before adding the new row you replace the old foreign key Id to the new generated id based on your created associative array.